# I don't get any data in profiler

Tags: reactjs, profiling, profiler

The profiler suported  in my project. But when I start recording and then stop that, it says: `No profiling data has been recorded.` I made my project with creat-react-app.

[image]

How can I observe my app's activities and what thing is missed?